# fetch data from database and display the values in database in laravel

Tags: laravel-5.4

I want to fetch values from database and display it in the view, but I didn't get a correct result.

This is my **controller**:

```php
class HrRequestController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $hr_request = HrRequest::all();

        return array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'pages' => $hr_request->toArray());
    }
}
```

and this is my **Model**:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class HrRequest extends Model
{

    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'hr_request';

    public $timestamps = false;
    /**
     * Fields.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'profile_role_id', 'hr_id', 'vacancy', 'experience', 'job_description', 'status', 'viewed',
    ];
}

view name:view-requests.blade.php
```

I have no idea n how to do this in view. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Controller:**

```
public function index()
{
    $hr_request = HrRequest::all();
    return view('view-requests')->with('hr_request', $hr_request);
}
```

**View:**

```
@foreach($hr_request as $row)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$row->profile_role_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row->vacancy}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row->experience}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row->job_description}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">View</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/view-hr-requests', 'HrRequestController@index');
```

It's working